# Why isn't this working and what is this error about mysqli_num_rows

Tags: php, mysqli

Hello i've been busy with a school project and i get the error:

```
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in     
/home/s1073623/domains/navarre.iie.nl/public_html/multimediadesign/inloggen.php on line 20
```

and this is the code:

```
<?php

ini_set ("display_errors", "On");

session_start();

include("connection.php");

    if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    if(empty($_POST['gebruikersnaam']) || empty($_POST['wachtwoord'])){
        echo "Niet alles is ingevuld!"; }


    else {
        $gebruikersnaam=$_POST['gebruikersnaam'];
        $wachtwoord=md5($_POST['wachtwoord']);
        $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE gebruikersnaam=".$gebruikersnaam." AND wachtwoord=".$wachtwoord." "; 
        $result=mysqli_query($connect, $sql); 

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1){    
            echo "Welkom"; 

                $_SESSION['gebruikersnaam']= $gebruikersnaam;
                $_SESSION['wachtwoord']= $wachtwoord;

            echo "Klik <a href=\"admin.php\">hier</a> voor het Dashboard."; 

            exit(); } 

            else { echo "Uw naam of wachtwoord zijn incorrect"; }

        }
    }


?>
```

Can somebody please help me it's important!!

Answer (score 0):

Your function mysqli_num_rows($result) show you an error because the error message say
$result is not a mysqli_result, it's a boolean.

And the only case when mysqli_result is a boolean, is  when the $sql you've made is wrong, so it return FALSE (which is a boolean). So if you want to debug this, you'll have to test your SQL request (in PHPmyadmin for example), and make it work, after your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should really prepare your query, it's not only safer but you can also avoid mistakes.

In your code if this table if the field you are checking are `VARCHARs` you will need to add quotes around these variables:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM users 
      WHERE gebruikersnaam= '$gebruikersnaam' AND wachtwoord='$wachtwoord' ";
```

---

using prepared statement:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE gebruikersnaam=? AND wachtwoord=? ";

/* create a prepared statement */
if ($result = mysqli_prepare($connect, $sql)) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result, "ss", $gebruikersnaam, $wachtwoord);

    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($result);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1){    
        echo "Welkom"; 
        //........
```